# UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Evaluation failed: ReferenceError: options is not defined

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, object, puppeteer

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
(async () => {
const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
const options = ["iframe"]
const url = 'https://www.loungeincomfort.com.au/'
const page = await browser.newPage();
await page.goto(url);
for (var i = 0; i < options.length; i++) {
    const frame = await page.$$eval(options[i], e => e.map(a => {
        const attrs = a.getAttributeNames();
        const len = attrs.length;
        const test = {};
        for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
            //test[attrs[i]].push({ label: "Hello World" })
            test[attrs[i]] = a.getAttribute(attrs[i])
        }
        return test;
    }))
    console.log(frame);
}
await browser.close();
})();
```

output is like this:

```
    [
    {
    "width": "640",
    "height": "360",
    "src": "https://www.youtube.com/embed/ZJPsDBCD4XU",
    "frameborder": "0",
    "allow": "accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture",
    "allowfullscreen": ""
    }
    ]
```

I want to add to the output the options[i] and the url I have added this in my code

```
        const test = {
             "object": options[i],
             "page": url
         };
```

but I get an error that options is not defined and I get the same error with url if I removed the "object": options[i],

What should I do to resolve this error?

So I have another problem in my output

output is like this:

```
[{
    "width": "1170",
    "height": "490",
    "style": "visibility: visible; width: 100%; margin-left: 0px; height: 301.538px; margin-top: -3.26923px; position: absolute;"
}]
```

I want to separate the style output into objects to be like this

I did some research about it and I couldn't find anything useful

```
[{
    "width": "1170",
    "height": "490",
    "style": {
           "visibility": "visible",
           "width": "100%",
           "margin-left": "0px",
           "height": "301.538px",
           "margin-top": "-3.26923px",
            "position": "absolute"

}}]
```

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code you're trying to add `options[i]` to is **client-side** code Puppeteer runs in the headless browser (the "page function"). `options` doesn't exist there.

According to [the documentation](https://pptr.dev/#?product=Puppeteer&version=v5.5.0&show=api-pageevalselector-pagefunction-args), you can have Puppeteer pass that value to the page function as an argument, so:

```
    const frame = await page.$$eval(options[i], (e, object, page) => e.map(a => {
//                                              ^ ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        const attrs = a.getAttributeNames();
        const len = attrs.length;
        const test = {object, page};
//                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^
        for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
            //test[attrs[i]].push({ label: "Hello World" })
            test[attrs[i]] = a.getAttribute(attrs[i])
        }
        return test;
    }), options[i], url)
//    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Comment: I have updated my question can you take a look and see if you can help me?

Comment: @MohamedEssam - Your edit asks a completely different question. Please post it as its own question. (The short answer is: Loop through the properties on the `style` property of the element [`a.style`], rather than looking at the string in the `style` attribute [`a.getAttribute(...)`].)

Answer (score 1):

This should solve your problem:

```
const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
    const options = ["iframe"];
    const url = "https://www.loungeincomfort.com.au/";
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.goto(url);
    for (var i = 0; i < options.length; i++) {
      const object = options[i];
      const frame = await page.$$eval(
        options[i],
        (e, { url, object }) =>
          e.map((a) => {
            const attrs = a.getAttributeNames();
            const len = attrs.length;
            const test = { object, page: url };
            for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
              //test[attrs[i]].push({ label: "Hello World" })
              test[attrs[i]] = a.getAttribute(attrs[i]);
            }
            return test;
          }),
        { url, object }
      );
      console.log(frame);
    }
    await browser.close();
```

Explanation: Pass url and object as additional arguments to $$eval